# Preferred style to organize imports in Java/Scala

Tags: scala

I would like to know the preferred/most common style to organize imports in Java/Scala source  code. I was following the style of putting java/scala imports first, followed by org. net. etc and then com.

```
import java.util....
import scala.collection...

import org.apache...
import net.liftweb.json

import com.mycompany...
```

Recently one of my team-mates has suggested this approach

```
- external libraries

- internal libraries

- scala
- java
```

like

```
import net.liftweb.json._

import com.mycompany.logging.Logger
import com.mycompany.api.Statsd
...

import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future, Await }
import java.util.Date
```

<strike>Would like to know the opinion of SO folks.</strike>

What would Martin say?

(Thereby positioning this question beyond the realm of mere opinion.  An answer to that question is verifiable.  And as Martin goes, so goes the community.)

How would Paul respond?

@extempore is known to have made extensive commits to the Scala code base simply to add `scala` in front of `util` because of some sort of package loading misbehavior in the presence of an empty directory named `util`.

Clearly, this is not a "soft" question.

Bonus question: Where does one put one's `_root_`s, if at all?

Comment: What build system are you using? You need to specify that, otherwise this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: I know the default order to be the other way around. Makes sense as for the ugly */_ the sequence then is first standard, then specific. One should ensure the IDE takes care of it. Eclipse: Organize Imports.

Comment: This becomes a problem when different team-mates working on same project prefer different IDEs. In our team ppl use Eclipse, IntelliJ and vim. That's why we were planning to follow a consistent style which involves some effort from the developer.

Comment: @Vishal : by "buildsystem" I meant stuff like Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc., not IDEs.

Comment: we use sbt for build.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato I don't see how the build tool influences this topic, since the behavior is precisely specified by the language (modulo bugs or gnats).

Comment: Vishal : thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately sbt's not my forte. @som-snytt : there are various nuances across built tools, usually related to *their* specifications/defaults. Also, the question as it stands is too general, so my intention was to limit its scope in order to reduce the risk of it being put on hold... as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use only absolute paths and no wildcard imports, then I agree that it's nice to put the third-party libs first, because they announce the dependencies early for the reader.

However, I have developed the habit of putting

```
import util._  // Try, etc
```

early so it's not quashed by subsequent imports that include a gazillion util packages.

It's also helpful to see other basics early:

```
import collection.mutable  // warning: yes you will find mutable in here
```

I've also come to appreciate leading with

```
import language.higherKinds  // if you aren't L3 maybe you shouldn't touch my code
```

Kind of kidding about that, but the SIP-18 imports are often put at the very bottom as if they were mere book keeping.

Assuming modularity and low fan-out, the list of third-party packages should be small anyway, and can snuggle close to the first top-level definition.

Update: Sometimes I exploit local imports. Recently I [snuck a language feature import in](https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/blob/51597daee67e28024328ec3be1f86de9819acf2e/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/util/StackTracing.scala#L67) that way, as I have done in the past, because my sense is that the effects (on the reader's sensibilities) are in fact local.

Answer (score 5):

Let your IDE do the job, it knows how to do it well.
Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ have tools to organize imports automatically.

In Eclipse: Source > Organize Imports

In NetBeans: Source > Organize Imports
You can also reorganize it for the entire project using Refactor > Inspect and transform.

In IntelliJ, I think it is: Code > Optimize imports.

Comment: It's not about the short-cut keys or how to configure within the IDE. But which style to follow.

Comment: I know it is not about the shortcuts. But your IDE can organize these imports  so you can figure out what it does and why (of if it makes sense [to you]). That can be a first step in finding what is the best order for imports...